# When is liveness probe retried in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, livenessprobe

I am trying to understand the retry behavior for liveness probe, its not clear from [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes).

I will to illustrate with an example. Consider the following spec for liveness probe

```
periodSeconds: 60
timeoutSeconds: 15
failureThreshold: 3
```

Lets assume the service is down

Which behavior is expected?

```
the probe kicks off at 0s
sees a failure at 15s, (due to timeoutSeconds 15) 
retry1 at ~15s, fail at ~30s and retry2 at ~30s, fail at ~45 (retry immediately after failure)
ultimately restart pod at ~45s (due to failureThreshold 3)
```

or

```
the probe kicks off at 0s
sees a failure at 15s, (due to timeoutSeconds 15) 
retry1 at ~60s, fail at ~75s and retry2 at ~120s, fail at ~135s (due to periodSeconds 60, doesnt really do retry after a failure)
ultimately restart pod at ~180s (due to failureThreshold 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`periodSeconds` is how often it checks. If you mean retry after crossing the failure threshold it never will because the container is full restarted from scratch.

Comment: i am referring to before crossing the failure threshold, in case k8s sees a failure, does it retry the probe immediately or does it simply wait for the next periodSeconds

Comment: It waits for the next period.